# MOQ WCF Service

Tags: wcf, moq

I need to MOQ *wcfClientService* while calling the `SomeMethod()`.

```
Class ABC : IABC
{

    internal WcfClientService  wcfClientService = new WcfClientService();

    public void SomeMethod(object pqr)
    {
        using(wcfClientService)
        {
            wcfClientService.Save(some parameters) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use some form of IoC (DI container). Using 'new' in this form will make it close to impossible to mock.

Comment: Yes this new word is the problem area. Can yuo suggest how to go about it.

Comment: It's a rather big change if you're not familiar with it, but have a look at things like: Unity (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection), AutoMapper *google and get many hits.

Comment: WcfClientService  inherits from an interface IWcfClientService, Can that make it possible to mock?

Comment: Class `ABC` should take `IWcfClientService` as a ctor parameter.  Then you can mock the interface.  Presumably this is so you can unit test your class.

Comment: Hi MattC I tried that but then my using statement is not working as i have interface then.

Answer (score 1):

With the current implementation, you cannot isolate the "ABC" class as it is tightly coupled with wcfClientService. I would strongly suggest things mentioned below:

1. Extract an interface IClientService. This makes your "ABC" class depend on an abstraction instead of a concrete implementation. It will help in short term to isolate "ABC" better for unit testing. In long term, your "ABC" class would not have to be changed if a "RestfulClientService" was to be used.
2. Consider introducing a Dependency Injection framework. Anything like a Spring.Net, Unity or Autofac should serve the purpose. Ideally, your production code should never instantiate a dependency. Let the framework take care of it.
3. Now, register and resolve a mock implementation of the interface using the DI framework and start unit testing the "ABC" class.